# Structure of inputs to scipy minimize function

Tags: python, numpy, function, scipy, minimize

I have inherited some code that is trying to minimize a function using `scipy.optimize.minimize`. I am having trouble understanding some of the inputs to the `fun` and `jac` arguments.

The call to minimize looks something like this:

```py
result = minimize(func, jac=jac_func, args=(D_neg, D, C), method = 'TNC' ...other arguments)
```

`func` looks like the following:

```py
def func(G, D_neg, D, C):
    #do stuff
```

`jac_func` has the following structure:

```py
def jac_func(G, D_neg, D, C):
    #do stuff
```

What I don't understand is where the `G` input to `func` and `jac_func` is coming from.  Is that somehow specified in the `minimize` function, or by the fact that the `method` is specified as `TNC`?  I've tried to do some research into the structure of this optimization function but I'm having trouble finding the answer I need.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The short answer is that `G` is maintained by the optimizer as part of the minimization process, while the `(D_neg, D, and C)` arguments are passed in as-is from the `args` tuple.

By default, `scipy.optimize.minimize` takes a function `fun(x)` that accepts one argument `x` (which might be an array or the like) and returns a scalar. `scipy.optimize.minimize` then finds an argument value `xp` such that `fun(xp)` is less than `fun(x)` for other values of `x`. The optimizer is responsible for creating values of `x` and passing them to `fun` for evaluation.

But what if you happen to have a function `fun(x, y)` that has some additional parameter `y` that needs to be passed in separately (but is considered a constant for the purposes of the optimization)? This is what the `args` tuple is for. The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize) tries to explain how the args tuple is used, but it can be a little hard to parse:

> args: *tuple, optional*
>
> Extra arguments passed to the objective function and its derivatives (Jacobian, Hessian).

Effectively, `scipy.optimize.minimize` will pass whatever is in `args` as the remainder of the arguments to `fun`, using the asterisk arguments notation: the function is then called as `fun(x, *args)` during optimization. The `x` portion is passed in by the optimizer, and the `args` tuple is given as the remaining arguments.

So, in your code, the value of the `G` element is maintained by the optimizer while evaluating possible values of `G`, and the `(D_neg, D, C)` tuple is passed in as-is.

Comment: Nice explanation!  Usually you would give a guess as to what you expect `G` to be, say `G0`. So instead of the form in the OP, you'd use `minimize(func, jac=jac_func, G0, args=(...,), ...)`.  If you don't pass one, it usually starts at `G=1.`  I think it's less confusing in this form, even if `G0=1.` as well.

Comment: I agree, it'd be nice to be more explicit about the initial guess for `G0` -- in fact I'd never seen a call to `minimize` that omitted it.

Comment: @lmjohns3 @askewchan: the initial guess `x0` is not an optional parameter, as you can see in the documentation. The user must always explicitly specify it, and there is no default value.

Comment: @pv. sure enough, thanks ! I've updated my answer just a bit to make it sound less like the minimizer is creating values for `x` from nowhere.

Comment: @pv. good catch --- as it happens almost all of the `scipy.optimize` functions require the starting point, except of course the one I used most recently: `curve_fit`, which indeed has a default of `1.0`.  I wonder why it's missing from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

For illustration purposes, we can print how `G` changes as `minimize` iterates to the local minimum. For example, consider the following case where the objective is to minimize a quadratic function of the form `f(x) = 2*x**2 - 4*x + 7` (which attains its minimum at `x=1`). Note that the parameters of the function (2, -4 and 7) were supplied as arguments to `obj_func` below.

The initial guess has to be supplied to start the algorithm.

As the output shows, starting from the initial value of 10, the function variable `G` descends to the minimizer.

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def obj_func(G, a, b, c):
    print(G)
    return a*G**2 + b*G + c

initial_guess = 10
a, b, c = 2, -4, 7

result = minimize(obj_func, x0=initial_guess, args=(a, b, c))

print(f"\nMinimizer = {result.x}")
print(f"  Minimum = {result.fun}")
```

which outputs the following:

```
[10.]
[10.00000001]
[8.99]
[8.99000001]
[6.82085113]
[6.82085114]
[1.62275043]
[1.62275045]
[1.]
[1.00000001]

Minimizer = [1.]
  Minimum = 5.0
```

---

Another example: Consider a two-variable function of the form `f(x, y) = (x - 1)**2 + (y - 2)**2`. The function attains its minimum at `(x, y) = (1, 2)` (and the minimum is 0).

Then starting from an initial point of `(x, y) = (0, 3)`, the function converges to the minimum as in the following.

```py
def obj_func(variable, x_offset, y_offset):
    x, y = variable
    print(f"x={x:.3f}, y={y:.3f}")
    return (x - x_offset)**2 + (y - y_offset)**2

initial_guess = [0, 3]
result = minimize(obj_func, initial_guess, args=(1, 2))
```

This prints the following which shows that the variables converge to the minimizer.

```
x=0.000, y=3.000
x=0.000, y=3.000
x=0.000, y=3.000
x=0.714, y=2.286
x=0.714, y=2.286
x=0.714, y=2.286
x=1.000, y=2.000
x=1.000, y=2.000
x=1.000, y=2.000
```

An important note about `minimize` is that the initial guess has to be an educated one especially if the objective function is complex, otherwise the algorithm may not converge. I find that to be a major source of unsuccessful optimization run.