# SciPy optimize.minimize with several variables

Tags: python, scipy, minimize

I'm trying to work with SciPy optimize.minimize usign several variables and I found a great explanation in: [Structure of inputs to scipy minimize function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843752/structure-of-inputs-to-scipy-minimize-function) in the case when the obective function is of the kind f(x,y) and the parameter to be optimizated is "x". 
But a question arises:
What if my objective function is of the kind f(x,y,z,u,v) and I want to optimze with respect to "y" and "u" (provided that f returns a scalar).

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new function with target variables going first in the list of parameters:

```
def g(y, u, x, z, v):
    return f(x, y, z, u, v)
```

(or use an analogous lambda).

Comment: can you tell me more about of the lambda function?

Comment: There's not much to say, it may be a bit more readable if your function is very short and you only need it once. See [python docs on it](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions). In your case it would be something like `minimize(lambda y, u, x, z, v: f(x, y, z, u, v), args=(x0, z0, v0))`