# Problems with minimizing 2-dimenshional function in Python's scipy.optimize

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I want to minimize 2-dimenshional function and have such Python code:

```
def f(x,y): 
    return (x-1.0)**2 + (y-2.0)**2

res = minimize(f, x0 = [0.0,0.0], bounds = ((-5,5),(-5,5)), method = 'L-BFGS-B')
```

And it doesn't work, because of such error (this is the last line of the error):

```
 TypeError: f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

What does it mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19845135/353839) help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to optimize a multidimensional function with `scipy.optimize.minimize`, you need to express it as a function that takes an array:

```
res = minimize(lambda x: f(*x), x0=...)
```