# How do I input multiple args in scipy.optimize minimize

Tags: optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I'm trying to solve a forces equilibrium consisting of three equations as constraints (Fx=0,Fy=0,Mx=0) and maximize the variable Vb, for which I set the objective function as -Vb. There are 4 variables that I don't know [phi, beta, gamma, delta_r] which form my vector of variables that corresponds to the guess x0.
Two more values are to be fixed, those are (beta,Vw)*

```
beta,Vw=rad(40),10

def fuerza_x(xs,beta,Vw):
    gamma,phi,Vb,delta_r = xs[0],xs[1],xs[2],xs[3]
    (beta,Vw)=args
    return Fuerzasx(phi,beta,gamma,Vb,Vw,delta_r)

def fuerza_y(xs,beta,Vw):
    gamma,phi,Vb,delta_r = xs[0],xs[1],xs[2],xs[3]
    beta,Vw=arguments
    return Fuerzasy(phi,beta,gamma,Vb,Vw,delta_r)

def momento_1(xs,beta,Vw):
    gamma,phi,Vb,delta_r = xs[0],xs[1],xs[2],xs[3]
    beta,Vw=arguments
    return mom(phi,beta,gamma,Vb,Vw,delta_r)

def objective(xs,beta, Vw):
    gamma,phi,Vb,delta_r = xs[0],xs[1],xs[2],xs[3]
    return -Vb


eq_cons = (
    {'type': 'eq', 'fun' : fuerza_x(xs,beta,Vw),'args': (beta,Vw) },
    {'type': 'eq', 'fun' : fuerza_y(xs, beta, Vw),'args': (beta,Vw) },
    {'type': 'eq', 'fun' : momento_1(xs,beta, Vw),'args': (beta,Vw) } )

x0 = np.array([ rad(4), rad(20),6, 0.2])
res = minimize(objective, x0,args=(beta,Vw), method='SLSQP',
               constraints=eq_cons, options={'ftol': 1e-9, 'disp': True})
```

I suppose that the mistake lies with the syntax used in the arguments tuple. I've researched lots of simmilar questions ([Structure of inputs to scipy minimize function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843752/structure-of-inputs-to-scipy-minimize-function)) but they don't fit for my case. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unless you expect us to copy and run the code, you need to be very clear about what's the problem.  If you get errors, show them, with full traceback.

Comment: Have you tried constrains like `{'type': 'eq', 'fun' : fuerza_x}`?  I'm not sure how the constraint `args` parameter relates to the one used in the main `minimize` call.  But you definitely don't want `fuerza_x(....)` when setting up the constraints.

Comment: Search on `[scipy] minimize constraints` gives many entries.  Surely there's something newer and more useful than your 2013 link.